# Understanding heap memory allocated by string empty checks

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management

While profiling a project I noticed we have an extension method for checking empty `IEnumerable<T>` and it was accidentally being used on a `string`, rather than a string-specific extension method. I wrote a small program to determine if the `IEnumerable<T>` version might be allocating and it seems to be, however I ran into unexpected results when I found that basically any method I wrote to check if a string was null or empty was allocating. Only using `string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)` could prevent allocations. Does anyone know why all of my methods are allocating memory to the heap? Is it simply because of the use of a function? If I avoid calling a function it doesn't allocate memory.

Here's the program demonstrating all of this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string myStr = "Blah";
        
        long startMemory = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
            bool empty = IEnumerableExtensions.IsNullOrEmpty(myStr);
        long memoryUsed = GC.GetTotalMemory(false) - startMemory;   
        
        // memory used: 8192
        Console.WriteLine($"IEnumerableExtensions.IsNullOrEmpty, memory used: {memoryUsed}");
            
        startMemory = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
            empty = StringExtensions.IsNullOrEmpty(myStr);
        memoryUsed = GC.GetTotalMemory(false) - startMemory;
        
        // memory used: 4040
        Console.WriteLine($"StringExtensions.IsNullOrEmpty, memory used: {memoryUsed}");
        
        startMemory = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
            empty = string.IsNullOrEmpty(myStr);
        memoryUsed = GC.GetTotalMemory(false) - startMemory;
        
        // memory used: 0
        Console.WriteLine($"string.IsNullOrEmpty, memory used: {memoryUsed}");
        
        startMemory = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
            empty = IsNullOrEmpty(myStr);
        memoryUsed = GC.GetTotalMemory(false) - startMemory;
        
        // memory used: 4040
        Console.WriteLine($"IsNullOrEmpty, memory used: {memoryUsed}");

        startMemory = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
            empty = (myStr == null || myStr.Length == 0);
        memoryUsed = GC.GetTotalMemory(false) - startMemory;
        
        // memory used: 0
        Console.WriteLine($"Direct (no function call), memory used: {memoryUsed}");
    }
    
    // Non-extension method
    private static bool IsNullOrEmpty(string str)
    {
        return str == null || str.Length == 0;
    }
}

public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        if (enumerable != null)
        {
            return !enumerable.Any();
        }

        return true;
    }
}
    
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this string str)
    {
        return str == null || str.Length == 0;
    }
}
```

If you want to see the program yourself, here's a DotNetFiddle version of it you can run: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2Zf0co

Comment: Well, [the source code for String.IsNullOrEmpty](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/string.cs#L793O) is exactly the same as your extension method, so it must have something to do with memory allocation for your `static` class.

Comment: That's simply not a reliable way of determining if a method allocates any memory.  Another thread running in the background could be allocating something, or some .NET  code (i.e. the GC itself) could be allocating memory.

Comment: True that. .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GC.GetTotalMemory` is not a very good method to use here because it counts native allocation too, for example when some function is called first time JIT will compile it into native code so app memory usage will increase (via native allocations). Move your code into some method and call it several times and you will see the difference.

Alternatively switch to `GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes(true)` instead of  `GetTotalMemory`.

For example for me second invocation results in:

```
IEnumerableExtensions.IsNullOrEmpty, memory used: 16384
string.IsNullOrEmpty, memory used: 0
StringExtensions.IsNullOrEmpty, memory used: 0
IsNullOrEmpty, memory used: 0
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YZBtS0)

As for allocations for the allocations for the `IEnumerableExtensions` - check out the [`IEnumerable<char>` implementation](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/String.cs,589) which is done via [`CharEnumerator`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/CharEnumerator.cs,10) which is a `class` so it at least partially explains the behaviour.

P.S.

In general (as noted in comments) it is not a fully reliable way to assess the allocated memory. Also you can look into using [`BenchmarkDotNet`](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) with [`MemoryDiagnoser`](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/guides/getting-started.html#step-6-analyze-results).

Comment: "Move your code into some method and call it several times and you will see the difference." Note that this isn't reliable in the general case as it can't determine if the method itself is allocating memory, just inconsistently.  For example, if the code uses a `Lazy` or some other caching mechanism to compute a value and save it for later.  And that's not even considering the possibility of other threads, finalizers, etc. affecting the count.

Comment: Thank you, switching to GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes(true) gave the results I was expecting.